# How can I access "androidx.savedstate.ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner" in Jetpack Compose 1.2.0?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-savedstate

I was able to access the below when I'm in Jetpack Compose 1.1.1

```
import androidx.savedstate.ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
```

However, when switching over to Jetpack Compose 1.2.0, I can no longer access it. It errors out stating

```
Unresolved reference: ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
```

e.g. In the view, I'm using it as below

```
ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(this, ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.get(composeView))
```

Is there any way I can still access it?

Answer (score 1):

In Jetpack Compose 1.2.0, we should use the below instead

```
import androidx.savedstate.findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
import androidx.savedstate.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
```

e.g. in the view

```
setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(composeView.findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner())
```

Comment: Is there any specific library that needs to be added to the project? As I am unable to use the same.

Answer (score 0):

At first for me, it was a bit confusing and after spending an hour I learn how to implement it.

First of all, you don't need to import anything as nowadays Android Studio itself adds the supported library. But I am specifying just for your reference if anyone has not enabled the autoImport feature in Android studio:

```
import androidx.savedstate.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner
```

Here is a complete example below:

```
val views = ComposeView(context = context)
views.setContent {
      Your @Composable function/component
}
views.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(LocalSavedStateRegistryOwner.current)
```